# Valid use of genstage Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a method, called `_start_extractor/1` and I am using a Phoenix endpoint to start it but with `GenStage`. such as

```
  defp start_snapshot_extractor(config) do
    name = :"snapshot_extractor_#{config.id}"
    case Process.whereis(name) do
      nil ->
        {:ok, pid} = GenStage.start_link(EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor, {}, name: name)
        pid
      pid -> pid
    end
    |> GenStage.cast({:snapshot_extractor, config})
  end
```

and in my `EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor` module, I am just doing this.

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor do
  use GenStage

  def init(args) do
    {:producer, args}
  end

  def handle_cast({:snapshot_extractor, config}, state) do
    _start_extractor(config)
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

  defp _start_extractor(config) do
  end
end
```

and then all the work is happening in `_start_extractor(config)`, Is that a correct us of `GenStage`? or just to start a process do I need `GenStage` or `GenServer` would be better choice for it?

Also when I stop/start my phoenix application, I want  to resume the process, So I am doing such as

```
Process.whereis(:"snapshot_extractor_#{extractor.id}")
|> get_process_pid(EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor, extractor.id)
|> GenStage.cast({:snapshot_extractor, get_config(extractor, :cloud)})
```

But I am not sure that I really need `GenStage` for this purpose?